# Can I reuse Storyboards created via Expression Blend for WP7.5 for android development?

Tags: android, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, xamarin.android

I have created a Windows Phone 7.5 Silverlight application. Most of the design and animations was done using Expression Blend.

It is a storybook app where user navigates from page to page. Each page have 4-5 storyboard animations running (ScaleX,Y, TransformX,Y, Rotation, etc.) Also I play SoundEffect when certain elements are clicked.

Now I am planning to have my same app for Android phones. I read a bit about commercial product [MonoforAndroid](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid).

What and all code can I reuse by using monoForAndroid? I believe navigation and playing sounds shouldn't be much difficult, but I am mainly concerned with Storyboard animations. Any suggestions please?

or

Should I be developing it from scratch using traditional Android development way. (I don't know anything so far about android dev).

Thanks for your time.

**Update:**  E.g. my app has a page that has a text block and few image elements with some sort of animations on most of them. User can drag the elements on the page and clicking some of the elements play small audio clip. So wondering how MVVM can fit in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to your question is: no, you can't.

By using Mono for Android you would be able to share non-UI and non-platform code across different platforms, but you still develop native UIs on top of this shared base for each platform you are targeting. Mono for Android provides full bindings to the Android SDK underneath to allow you to define this native UI through C# rather than Java. By using that approach you can provide a native experience without having to rewrite core application logic every time. In this case, it sounds like you are looking to share the UI itself, rather than the business logic.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, actually may app doesn't have any data retrieval or business calculations or stuff. It's just the storyboard animations and SoundEffects.

Comment: You'll need to redo that stuff on each platform then to deliver the best experience.

Answer (score 1):

If you had a good separation between the UI and the Model (and ViewModel is you implemented the MVVM pattern) you should be able to reuse all the Model + ViewModel layer. However you would need to rewrite the UI part since every platform has a different framework for the UI elements. [How to develop cross platform](http://ndc2011.macsimum.no/mp4/Day2%20Thursday/Track4%201620-1720.mp4)

Comment: Thanks, I will look at the video. I am not sure how MVVM applies to my application as there is no data or calculations or stuff involved. I edited my question above with some more info on my app.